# Remove a character and specific immediately trailing characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings in python of the form `ABC_###` where ### is a number from 1-999. I want to remove the _ and any leading 0s from the number, basically any `_`, `_0`, or `_00` to get the format `ABC 4` or `ABC 909`. I can think of a couple of dumb ways to do this but no smart ways, so I'm here :)

Comment: Try `(?<=ABC)_0*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
_0*
```

which matches zero or more `0`'s after an `_`, and replace it with `' '`.

```py
import re

strs = ['ABC_2545', 'ABC_001', 'ABC_04']
for s in strs:
    print(re.sub(r'_0*', ' ', s))
```

Output:

```
ABC 2545
ABC 1
ABC 4
```

Comment: @yuuuu good to hear - I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

As long as the format is consistent, then using `string`'s `split` method is fine.

```
my_list = ['ABC_001', 'DEF_023']
new_format = (f'{letters} {int(nums)}' for letters, nums in (elem.split('_') for elem in my_list))
print(list(new_format))
```

Strings are returned with a generator.  In this case converted to a list to be printed.

```
['ABC 1', 'DEF 23']
```

*edited to return a string formatted rather than a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In case your list is not a Python list, and it's stored in a file one line per element, try this:

```
import re

fi = open('myList.txt', 'r')
fo = open('myNewList.txt', 'w+')

for line in fi:
  fo.writelines(re.sub(r'_0*', ' ', line))

fi.close()
fo.close()
```